# GoogleMaps 3.7 map displays blank in IE

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

[this page](http://www.calvert.ch/tools/geocoder.htm), which worked fine for the last couple of years, now displays a blank map, apparently since 15 May 2012, when 3.9 was released.

Following the release of [version 3.9](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/topics), applications requesting 3.6 are served 3.7, which seems to be the cause, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I've developed a squint from re-reading the code, but I can't see what's amiss. Is there a kind soul who could help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check the settings of your application. Because when you run the web application on IE9 modifies Document mode from IE9 to internet explorer 7. This could be cause by an setting in your IIS or apache depends of web application even in your markup of your application. to replicate the error

1. Close the IE9 if it's open
2. Open the browser and open the developers tools f12
3. Put the url
4. Check the document mode it's change to IE7

[image: Here's an screenshoot]

Comment: Thanks, you're spot on. In 3.6 and before I had had to force IE=ie7 emulation to avoid the blank-screen in IE9. Now that 3.7 or later is forced (and works in native IE9), the best solution seems to be v=3.8 and X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge". ...until the next incompatibility :( I sometimes wonder how many millions of man-hours mankind has wasted fixing the mess created by browser wars.